# Laravel's "Given data is invalid"when using a form request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

So I have a Form Request that has validation rules and some messages.

This is my function in the controller (called via vue.axios)

```
public function store(TaskFormRequest $request, TaskService $service): JsonResponse
{
    $data = $request->validated();

    if (!$task = $service->create($data)) {
        return JsonResponse::create(['message' => __('Can\'t create Task')], 400);
    }

    return JsonResponse::create(
        [
            'task_id' => $task->id,
            'message' => __('Task was successfully added.'),
        ]
    );
}
```

It works OK, except that the moment store is called on (and $request is being considered TaskFormRequest instance) when the data is not validated it returns "The given data is invalid" JsonResponse in addition to the error messages from the form.

This would be fine, but the message itself is buried deep in Vendor and I can't apply any translations on it without it being a hassle.

This is my form request:

```
public function authorize(): bool
{
    return $this->user()->role === 'administrator';
}

public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        'subject' => 'required',
        'date' => 'nullable|date_format:Y-m-s',
        'user' => 'nullable|exists:users,id',
        'task_list_id' => 'required|exists:task_lists,id',
        'privacy' => 'array',
    ];
}

public function messages() {
    return [
        'subject.required' => __("Task name is empty")
    ];
}
```

I want to all together stop this response and just leave the errors from the form. Or at the least customize it.

**EDIT:** I think the problem is that the request is empty? If I enter a `null` default in the `store` function's arguments, I can check for empty $request and return a JsonResponse, but then it doesn't go through the normal validation process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was also struggling with the same problem. You would get "The given data is invalid" error if your validation code is in try block. Remove it out from try block and you will get proper error response as Laravel gives.

Answer (score 0):

What happen when you remove you `messages()` function ?

(`date_format:Y-m-s` seems wrong, should'nt it be `date_format:Y-m-d` ? )

Comment: Then it returns the basic "Task name is required" or whatever in addition to the "The given data is invalid". Yeah, there was a typo in the date :) It's not required so I wasn't even filling in any dates.

Comment: are you sure the `__("Task name is empty")` si returning anything ? Does your language json file is correct ?

Comment: It does - the language system in this app is bizarre, but it works. Problem is only with "The given data is invalid" json message response.

Answer (score 0):

The validator throws a `Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException` that you can intercept in the `App\Exceptions\Handler->render()` before it is sent to the parent Class in the vendor.

```
if ($exception instanceof ValidationException) {
    //choose the structure you want. the Validation exception has many methods
    return response()->json(['status' => 'error', 'message' => $exception->getMessage()], 422);
}
```

---

edit:
to intercept the error in the form request itself, declare the following method:

```
public function failedValidation(\Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator $validator)
{
    throw (new \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException($validator))
                ->errorBag($this->errorBag)
                ->redirectTo($this->getRedirectUrl());
}
```

Comment: but is there any way to intercept and cancel the whole response only for this particular formrequest

Comment: @MaximilianBerbechelov edited the answer. you can intercept the error by FormRequest if you need to. what's inside the method is the default result implemented by laravel